# How to add json data to client url

Tags: java, json, rest

I am using a simple main method java class to call a restful URL to consume the application. I created a client and tried to call the URL. My question is: **how do I add json data as a query parameter?** Below is my method.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Client client = Client.create();

            WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://10.123.85.120:8080/myWebService/updateModel.do?abc=33589&applicationId=8&uuid=9a26038f-6dd1-40b6-b847-f2fd16366fc0&jsonData={"NostudentsOrganized": 1,"Noofcourses": 20,"Noofattendedstudents": 5}");

            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
            }

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            System.out.println(output);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to add the query parameter to another server call?

Comment: no here i am getting compile time error.please modify the url here

Comment: Ahh sorry didnt see the rest of the query string

Comment: Do you specifically want it on as  a query param or can you do a post?

Comment: you should send as POST  parameter since GET have limited url length.

Comment: you can refer to this URL --> http://crunchify.com/json-manipulation-in-java-examples/

Comment: I dont think its the length in this case or the server should return a  414 (Request-URI Too Long)  I think it may be the spaces in the json that need to be replaced with %20 however this would break the json on the receiving end

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes in the middle of the string literal: e.g. use `\"NostudentsOrganized\"` instead of just `"NostudentsOrganized"`.

Comment: thanks for your reply now i am not getting compile time error but i am getting run time error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 142

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String jsonData = "{'NostudentsOrganized': 1,'Noofcourses': 20,'Noofattendedstudents': 5}";
String uri = "http://10.123.85.120:8080/myWebService/updateModel.do?abc=33589&applicationId=8&uuid=9a26038f-6dd1-40b6-b847-f2fd16366fc0&jsonData" + URLEncoder.encode(jsonData, "UTF-8");

WebResource webResource = client.resource(uri);
//rest of the code
```